# Prepared Statements php array from csv into mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, fgetcsv

New to prepared statements, trying to insert php array into database with mysqli.

```
 if(isset($_FILES['upload'])) {

                                if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], 'r')) !== FALSE) {
                                     while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                                    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO sov ('BID', 'costcode', 'bidpack', 'item', 'um', 'qty', 'est', 'up') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                                    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6], $row[7]);
                                    $stmt->execute();
               
                                    }
     
                                               fclose($handle);
                                            }
                                            
                                            }
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in...
```

I tried LOAD DATA INFILE and got cpanel permission errors so please don't suggest.

Comment: 'BID', 'costcode' - single quotes are used in SQL to delimit strings, while you are using them to delimit column names

Comment: hot damn! it works.